# Transparent NavigationView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, ios-navigationview

I am trying to make a transparent NavigationViewso that there is no moving picture in the background.
if I add opacity to NavigationView, I see the desired image

.background(Color.clear) dont work

```
ZStack {
            Color("FF0000").background(
                Image("Background").resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                
            NavigationStack  {
                
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20){
                   
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
}
```